# CSS to view full slider image in mobile view

Tags: css

I have a website which contains slider in home page. In large screen the slider image in properly fits but in mobile view the slider image does not fully fit the screen size instead only center part of image is viewed in mobile view.

Below are the screenshot of both laptop and mobile view:

Laptop View of Website slider

[image: Laptop View of Website slider]

Mobile View of Website slider

[image]

I want slider image to fully viewed in mobile view also.

Laptop view CSS

```
.rs-slider.style1 .slider-content.slide1 {
  background: url(assets/images/slider/h2-1.jpg);
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.rs-slider.style1 .slider-content {
  padding: 250px 0;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Mobile View Css

```
.rs-slider.style1 .slider-content.slide1 {
  background: url(assets/images/slider/h2-1.jpg);
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .rs-slider.style1 .slider-content {
    padding: 175px 0;
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size: contain` for the mobile view.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .rs-slider.style1 .slider-content.slide1 {
        background-size: contain;
    }
}
```